# Class 'Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Event' not found in Laravel/Lumen

Tags: symfony, rackspace

When Trying to install Rackspace package (`composer require rackspace/php-opencloud`), getting the following error
`Class 'Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Event' not found`.
I have installed symfony package but that could not worked out.
Kindly help me out for this.

Comment: did you found the issue?

Answer (score 3):

Try to install the required package

```
composer require symfony/event-dispatcher
```

Comment: FYI,  

 "require": {
        "php": "^7.2.5",
        "campaignmonitor/createsend-php": "^6.1",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0",
        "illuminate/mail": "^7.22",
        "laravel/lumen-framework": "^7.0",
        "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "^1.0",
        "rackspace/php-opencloud": "^1.16",
        "spatie/laravel-json-api-paginate": "^1.7",
        "spatie/laravel-query-builder": "^2.8",
        "symfony/event-dispatcher": "^5.1",
        "tymon/jwt-auth": "^1.0"
    },